# Redirect to fallback file if first attempt fails

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([^/\.]+)/(.+)$ themes/current/images/$1/$2 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/([^/\.]+)/(.+)$ modules/$1/images/$2 [L,NC]
```

The idea is that it does the following:

```
// Rewrite this...
images/calendar/gear.png

// ... to this
themes/current/images/calendar/gear.png

// HOWEVER, if that rewritten path doesn't exist, rewrite the original URL to this:
modules/calendar/images/gear.png
```

The only things that change here are `calendar` and `gear.png`, the first of which could be any other single word and the latter the file name (possibly with path) to an image file.

I can rewrite the original URL to the first rewrite as shown in the example just fine, but what I cannot do is get my .htaccess to serve up the file from the other, fallback location if the first location 404s. I was under the impression that not using `[L]` in my first `RewriteRule` would rewrite the URL for `RewriteCond`.

The problem I'm having is that instead of serving the fallback file, the browser just shows a 404 to the first rewritten path (`themes/current/calendar/gear.png`), instead of falling back to `modules/calendar/gear.png`. What am I doing wrong?

Please note that my regex isn't perfect, but I can refine that later. Right now I'm concerning myself with the rewrite logic itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fallthrough rules are fraught with bugs.  My general recommendation is than any rule with a replacement string other than `-` should trigger an internal redirect to restart the `.htaccess` parse.  This avoids the subrequest and URI_PATH bugs.

Next once you go to 404, again in my experience this is unrecoverable.   I have a fragment which does something similar to what you are trying to do:

```
# For HTML cacheable blog URIs (a GET to a specific list, with no query params, 
# guest user and the HTML cache file exists) then use it instead of executing PHP

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !blog_user
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}%{QUERY_STRING}  =GET               [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:DOCUMENT_ROOT_REAL}/blog/html_cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(article-\d+|index|sitemap.xml|search-\w+|rss-[0-9a-z]*)$ \
            blog/html_cache/$1.html                              [L,E=END:1]
```

Note that I do the conditional test in filesystem space and not URI (Location) space.  So this would map in your case to

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/themes/current/images/$1/$2l -f
RewriteRule ^images/(.+?)/(.+)$ themes/current/images/$1/$2 [L]
```

Though do a phpinfo() to check to see if your hosting provider uses an alternative to **DOCUMENT_ROOT** if it is a shared hosting offering e.g an alternative environment variable as mine uses **DOCUMENT_ROOT_REAL**.

The second rule will be picked up on the second processing past after the internal redirect.